# PHP and JS within HTML

Tags: php, javascript

This is what I am trying to do:

I have a data.php page.

In this page I have mostly HTML. Within the HTML I have some PHP code, designated by

```
<?php   

?>
```

Now, I am trying to insert JavaSript with in the PHP; something like below:

```
<?php   
     <script type="text/javascript">

     </script>

?>
```

But I get 'syntax error' notification from Adobe Dreamweaver.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should learn the languages / technologies you're trying to use, instead of relying so heavily on an IDE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to end your PHP and then start the Javascript

```
<?php
...php here...
?>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     </script>

<?php
... more php ...
?>
```

Comment: You can still include PHP tags between the script tags if necessary though :) Example in my answer. Can be very messy when trying to maintain the code though.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't enclose Javascript into `<?php ... ?>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is executed on the server, before the request reaches the client. Javascript is executed on the client. Therefore you need PHP to echo the javascript.

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx">';
echo 'SOME JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONALITY';
echo '</script>';

?>
```

Not that I recommend it

Answer (score 0):

If you must enclose JavaScript within PHP tags then you can do something such as this:

```
<?php   
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

     echo '</script>';

?>
```

Keep in mind that you may have to escape quotes if you need to use the same types within the echo statement. This can be done by adding a back slash - `\"`.

I was recently involved on a project myself where we needed to do some encryption using PHP and use the values returned within the JavaScript but our code was in the following form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Do something in JavaScript
    var x = <?php echo $calculatedValue; ?>;
    // etc..
</script>
```

It can be a nightmare to maintain but it is better form than the first example in this answer.